# Can I use NPM with a Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova project in the IDE?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Creating a web application in VS2015-preview allows the user to utilize NPM within the IDE. I cannot find a way to do this in a "Tools for Apache Cordova" project. I would like to effectively run `npm install underscore --save` within the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently running npm command from IDE is not supported for Tools for Apache Cordova project. Since Node.js is installed and configured as a part of Tools for Apache Cordova installation, you can use command prompt to run the npm command.